# Type Checking with TypeScript using Firebase Callable functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, types, casting, google-cloud-functions

I am using TypeScript to write callable Cloud Functions with Firebase, and it is important that I receive data of a certain type.

My function declaration is as follows:

```
export const questionnaireSubmit = https.onCall(async (data: questionnaireDoc): Promise<apiOut> => {})
```

Because I defined `questionnaireDoc` as an interface, using `data instanceof questionnaireDoc` gives the following error in my IDE:

```
'questionnaireDoc' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)
```

When calling this function in a TypeScript program, I can use the `HttpsCallable<parameterType,returnType>` type from "firebase/functions" to define its input type, but this relies on the client code explicitly setting the type and using a language that supports explicit types.

Right now, I am checking the existence of necessary properties using the following within my cloud function:

```
        switch (undefined) {
            case <unknown>data.property1:
            case <unknown>data.property2:
            case <unknown>data.property3:
            case <unknown>data.property4:
            case <unknown>data.property5:
            case <unknown>data.property6:
            case <unknown>data.property7:
            case <unknown>data.property8:
            case <unknown>data.property9:
                throw new https.HttpsError("invalid-argument", "Missing required field(s)");
        }
```

But this workaround does not seem necessary or scalable.

**What is the best practice to ensure inputs passed to Firebase Callable functions are correct within the function using TypeScript?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `onCall` function [is generic](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/blob/27a49837ea7b74d9d2926e74c387f45704d57889/src/v2/providers/https.ts#L300) and can take both a request and a return type. I think this might help:

```
export const questionnaireSubmit = 
  https.onCall<questionnaireDoc,apiOut>(async (data) => {
    // ...
  })
```

Comment: Thank you! I am very new to using generic types with TypeScript. When I rewrite the function as you have written above, my IDE gives the error: `Expected 0 type arguments, but got 2.`. My understanding is that the generic types will carry out the function but allows you to reference the input or output type without actually knowing what it is. Will this allow me to restrict types that are not `questionnaireDoc` from being passed into this function?

Comment: To me, there's no generics on `onCall` method. What is this magic? I'm calling `functions.https.onCall`.

Comment: The `onCall` function v2 is generic. The v1 [is not generic](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/blob/27a49837ea7b74d9d2926e74c387f45704d57889/src/providers/https.ts#L58)!